# How I can make it that you cant go to a site if you aren t logged (middleware)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working right now on a webpage, using express. On my navigation bar I added a "Home" which brings you to another page. But now I want to make it so that you can only get to the page using the Home button if you are logged in. (using middleware) I tried something but did not know what to put in . 
Thanks for help 
Taris

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const session = require('express-session')
const register = require('./data/register.js');
const login = require('./data/login.js');

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(session({
    secret: toString(Date.now()),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));
app.use(prover);

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.get('/', loggedin, (req, res) =>  {
    res.render('login.ejs', {error: undefined});
});

app.get('/register', loggedin,(req, res) => {
    res.render('register.ejs', {error: undefined});
});

app.get('/user/:id/home', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs', {userdata: req.session.userdata});
});
app.get('/info', loggedin,(req, res) => {
    res.render('info.ejs', {error: undefined});

});
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const response = login(req.body.name, req.body.password);
    if(!response.id){
        let error;
        if(response == "wrong name") error = `No user named "${req.body.name}"`;
        else error = "wrong password";
        res.render('login.ejs', {error:error});
    } else {
        req.session.userdata = response;
        req.session.userdata.name = req.body.name;
        console.log(`${req.body.name} logged in at ${getTime()} at the devide ip ${req.ip.slice(7)} ${req.ips}`);
        res.redirect(`/user/id={${response.id}}/home`);
    };


});

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const response = register(req.body.name, Date.now(), req.body.email, req.body.password);
    if(response != "worked") res.render('register.ejs', {error: response});
    else res.render('login.ejs', {error: `You are now registered as ${req.body.name}`});
});

app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session) {
        try{
            console.log(`${req.session.userdata.name} logged out at ${getTime()} at the devide ${req.ip.slice(7)} ${req.ips}`)
        } catch(error){
            console.log(`"Err" logged out at ${getTime()} at the devide ${req.ip.slice(7)} ${req.ips}`);
        }
        req.session.destroy(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                return res.redirect('/');
            };
        });
    };
});

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function getTime() {
    let today = new Date();
    let date = today.getDate()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear();
    let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    let dateTime = date+' '+time;
    return dateTime;
};

function loggedin(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session && req.session.userdata) {
        res.redirect(`/user/id={${req.session.userdata.id}}/home`);
    } else {
        next();
    };
};
//This is where i tried it, but i dont know what to put in

function prover(req, res, next) {
    if(req.body.name == undefined){
        next();
    }
}

server.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Online auf port 5000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your routes have the loggedin middleware except `/user/:id/home`. If `/user/:id/home` is the route that gets called when you hit 'Home' then the middleware should be placed there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basic : Whenever a user is logged in. You can create a session and then check if session exist in the middleware.

For a more sophisticated approach, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport